# Increase in CloudSQL Postgres instance temporary files (How to delete them?)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

There is an exponential increase in temporary files and they are not being released correctly. In Googlee Cloud SQL Postgres we do not have permissions to execute the pgsql_temp directory deletion.

Rebooting the machine is supposed to delete the base / pgsql_temp directory but it doesn't.

I can't stop the master either since it has an associated replica.

How can I force delete temporary files?

SELECT datname, temp_files AS "Temporary files", pg_size_pretty(temp_bytes) AS "Size of temporary files" FROM pg_stat_database;

[temp Files Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxoNl.png)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried [DISCARD in Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-discard.html)?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE RESOLVED**
Hi,

for other people that may happen to them. We are doing massive loads on the database, this increases the WAL Logs.

If the system normally had this volume, the recommendation made by google is to consider keeping less backups or completely disable point-in-time recovery.

until it is deleted, in default backup configuration after 7 days

Thanks